# MYSQL default RAM consumption

Tags: mysql, database, memory, memory-management, ram

I have a 32GB RAM MYSQL server. It's still totally new and no database attached except the default ones. However, when I run `free -m` command, I get the following:

```
       total     used     free    shared  buff/cache available
Mem:   32768     2972     29718     10       76        29692
Swap:  16384     0        16384
```

When I contacted the host, they told me that MYSQL consumes 10% of the main memory by default and they advised me to configure the following parameters:

```
key_buffer_size = 8192M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 10922M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16384M
```

Those values I think represent the maximum consumption that could be allocated not what's consumed by default and they are the recommended values by MYSQL. For example 8192M / 32768M (total memory) = 25% which is the recommended value. Can anyone explain this memory consumption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Those values I think represent the maximum consumption that could be allocated not what's consumed by default

The entire InnoDB buffer pool is allocated at server startup, so reducing the size of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` will reduce the initial memory footprint used by MySQL.

I believe the same is also true of other MySQL buffers such as `key_buffer_size` and `myisam_sort_buffer_size`.

However, you should consider the actual server workload when tuning these parameters. The amount of memory used at startup is irrelevant; the interesting thing is how the memory usage looks when the server is in use with real databases.

Since you mentioned (elsewhere) that you're using Jelastic, you should delete the `#Jelastic autoconfiguration mark.` line from your `my.cnf` (usually at/near line 1) if you want to manually tune these settings; otherwise they are scaled automatically to suit your cloudlet scaling limit (i.e. your changes will be overwritten each time you adjust cloudlet limits or restart MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

**key_buffer_size**

The maximum size of the **key_buffer_size** variable is 4 GB on 32 bit machines, and larger for 64 bit machines. MySQL recommends that you keep the key_buffer_size less than or equal to 25% of the RAM on your machine.

**innodb_buffer_pool_size**

Recommended range: 60~80%

[MySQL 5.7 and it’s online buffer pool resize feature](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html) should make this an easier principle to follow.